# Why does link_to when used in a partial return a link to the parent object rather than the actual object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, link-to

So I have two models, Users that belong_to Organization (which has_many users). I'm using a partial to display all the users that belong to any one particular organization, and this is working fine if I output just the name (it correctly names all the users). However when I change the partial code to provide link_to user.name, the returned links are all links to the parent Organization rather than the individual child objects. What am I doing wrong?

Relevant code:

Organizations Controller

```
def show
@organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
@users_index = User.joins(:organization).where(organizations: {id: @organization.id})
end
```

Organization.show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @organization.organization_name) %>
<h1><%= @organization.organization_name %></h1>
<h2>Your Organization's Users:</h2>
<%= render partial: "users_index", collection: @users_index %>
```

_users_index.html.erb code:

```
<p class="users"><%= link_to users_index.name %></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**link_to**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

I think the core of the issue, as alluded to in the other answer, is your `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to users_index.name %>
```

The `link_to` helper method basically works like this:

```
<%= link_to "Your Link Text", link_path %>
```

I don't see how your application will be able to load the correct link path without your definition, irrespective of whether you added it to the helper or not.

I presume that your rendered link will point to "#", not the "parent object" as you alluded.

--

**Fix**

I'd do this:

```
#app/views/organization/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: "users_index", collection: @users_index, as: :user %>

#app/views/organization/_users_index.html.erb
<p class="users"><%= link_to user.name, user %></p>
```

This should set the correct `link_to` helper method for you

--

**Models**

Further, I would also address the `associations` in your models

You're currently calling `users` in the most inefficient way. [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) work to remedy this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :organization
end

#app/models/organization.rb
Class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb
Class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @organization = Organization.find params[:id]
      @users_index = @organization.users
   end
end
```

Comment: Perfect - this has worked exactly as I was hoping it would. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks Rich. I was using the more unwieldy code because I needed it in another part of the project (to ensure only the users of the current organization are shown here). This update works too, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your relationship properly then you can use:

`@users_index = @organization.users`

And then you need to loop through @users_index and pass that to your partial.

```
@users_index.each do |user|
    <%= render "users_index", :user => user %>
end
```

And in your partial, change to:

```
<p class="users"><%= link_to user.name, user %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where would I set up the @ users_index = @organization.users code? In the Users Controller? I'm using the ActiveRecord query because I only want to retrieve users that belong to the current/active organization. When I tried your code it throws the error that there's no method "user" defined for the class (which is an Organization identified by its primary key) in my case.